# Importing ReactJS components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I'm new to ReactJS, and I'm building enough components that they should probably be spread out over several different files (just for organization/readability). However, I can't seem to get the `import` function working. Here's a simplified version of the scenario I'm dealing with:

`ExportMe.jsx`:

```
class A extends React.component {
    render() {
        return <h1>Data below:</h1>
    }
}
export default class B extends React.component {
    render() {
        return <div><A/><span>{this.props.data}</span></div>
    }
}
```

`Importer.jsx`:

```
import {B} from "ExportMe.jsx";
$.getJSON( "./data/json_files/Intro.json", function(data) {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <TextDisplay data={data}/>,
        document.getElementById('centerPanel')
    );
})
```

In the HTML, I simply write `<script type="text/jsx" src="jsx/Importer.jsx"></script>` but I get the following error in my console:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "ExportMe.jsx" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

I'm not even using RequireJS, and importing it doesn't resolve this error. If I also try to include `<script type="text/jsx" src="jsx/ExportMe.jsx"></script>` in the HTML, then I get an error telling me exports is not defined. How can I deal with this, or do I really need to combine all of my ReactJS components into a single file?

Comment: Are you using a bundler such as webpack? import and require don't currently work in the browser by themselves without some kind of wrapper or transpiler.

Comment: Yes you need to combine and bundle them in a single file before you add it to HTML. Check out this starter project create react app https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

Answer (score 2):

Remove the curly braces, and if the exportme.jsx file is in the same folder as importer.jsx, you should prefix the file with './' like so:
import B from "./ExportMe.jsx";

Answer (score 1):

in your import, change

```
import {B} from "ExportMe.jsx";
import B from "ExportMe.jsx";
```

Use the {functionName} when you import a function

Answer (score 0):

Here you have 2 problems with the import. Your code should look like this

`ExportMe.jsx`:

```
class A extends React.component {
    render() {
        return <h1>Data below:</h1>
    }
}
export default class B extends React.component {
    render() {
        return <div><A/><span>{this.props.data}</span></div>
    }
}
export class C extends React.component {
    render() {
        return <div><A/><span>{this.props.data}</span></div>
    }
}
```

`Importer.jsx`:

```
import B, {C} from './ExportMe.jsx';
```

`B` will be imported without braces because it's set as default exported object in the `ExportMe.jsx` file;
'C' will be imported with braces, because it's also exported, but not as `default`

NOTE: If you type `import B from 'ExportMe.jsx';` - it will look over node packages, instead of files. That's why you have to use `./` when you import form files.